# My Ubuntu kernel config file does not recognizes all memory available to the system,but only half

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, memory, kvm, arm

The project that I've been working on since 2 years is to enable KVM (with the support of libvirt and virt-manager) on a recent version of Linux and of its kernel on the old but still nice ARM Chromebook model xe303c12.

My goal is to virtualize FreeBSD 13.2 for armV7. I've almost completed the project. At today I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 (but it works also with Devuan 5); KVM is enabled; libvirt 9.7.0 and virt-manager are working great. 
I've almost been able to virtualize FreeBSD. Almost, because I've found a problem that I need to fix or the whole project will die. Ubuntu recognizes only 1 GB of memory free, but the ARM Chromebook has 2 GB of memory soldered to the motherboard. So, 1 GB of memory has been lost during the transition from the first project I tried to enable KVM with an old kernel (and ubuntu) version, that you can find here:

http://www.virtualopensystems.com/en/solutions/guides/kvm-on-chromebook/#setting-up-the-boot-medium

and my project, that uses a more recent kernel version (5.4) and ubuntu version (22.04). I think that when I have recompiled the kernel, I've lost some kernel entries that are enabled on the 3.13 kernel used by the developers at the Virtual Open System. Sadly, I have no idea about which entries my kernel config are missing.

I have checked the available memory for the OS giving the command:

```
# free -m
```

If I don't recover 1 GB of memory, I can't virtualize FreeBSD, because only 1 GB is a very small amount of memory to be able to run the host and the guest OS.

So, can you help me to find which kernel entries I should add to have all the 2 GB of memory available?

Virtual Open System offers it's own kernel config file, that I have saved here:

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/j4B54TChKD/

using their kernel config file I see that I have a total of 2 GB of memory available (I spend 400 MB to load Linux, so only 600 remains; it's not good. In fact, I get a lot of qemu crashes), but If I use my config file the OS starts with only 1 GB.

I want share two kernel config files :

1. the kernel 3.13 dmesg log file where 2 GB is recognized,here :

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/gsw9SM4zY3/

2. the kernel 5.4 dmesg log file where only 1 GB is recognized,here :

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/W6Mgj4jGg2/

I've compared the dmesg logs (kernel 3.13 vs kernel 5.4 config files) and I think this is the reason why I have only 1 GB of memory available :

OF: fdt: Ignoring memory range 0x40000000 - 0x80000000

This line is not present on the kernel 3.13 dmesg log file,but it is on the kernel 5.4 dmesg log file. The dtb file generation seems involved.

What do you think ?

Comment: have you checked the devicetree files that your old system probably used to inform the kernel about present hardware?

Comment: (2GB is really not much RAM, kudos for getting it this far, with only half of that!)

Comment: you mean that I could use the dtb file provided by virtual open system,instead of using the dtb file that I have reconfigured when I have recompiled the kernel 5.4 ?

Comment: You should probably at least compare the two!

Comment: I want share two kernel config files :

1) the kernel 3.13 dmesg log file where 2 GB is recognized,here :

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/gsw9SM4zY3/

2) the kernel 5.4 dmesg log file where only 1 GB is recognized,here :

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/W6Mgj4jGg2/


I compared the dmesg logs and I think this is the reason :

 OF: fdt: Ignoring memory range 0x40000000 - 0x80000000

This line is not present on the kernel 3.13 dmesg log file,but it is on the kernel 5.4 dmesg log file. The dtb file generation seems involved. Can you help here ?